# Extjs4 how to add annotation on line chart

Tags: extjs, annotations

I want to do the same function like this
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart?hl=zh-TW

Does extjs have the same chart?

thx

Answer (score 1):

Theres is nothing right out of the box with ExtJS for this but you could build your own using a `linechart`, `scatterchart` and a `DataView` on the side to display the comments. (Building the time slider at the bottom would be a little harder but it can be done as well).

What I would do however, is avoid myself a lot of work and follow this tutorial on how to integrate Google Charts with ExtJS: http://code.betancourt.us/ext-google-visualization/

Good luck!